# inequality how to get

Tags: analysis

> $$\left| {{a_n} + \frac{{{a_{n - 1}}}}{z} + ... + \frac{{{a_1}}}{{{z^{n - 1}}}} + \frac{{{a_0}}}{{{z^n}}}} \right| \ge \left| {{a_n}} \right| - \left| {\frac{{{a_{n - 1}}}}{z} + ... + \frac{{{a_1}}}{{{z^{n - 1}}}} + \frac{{{a_0}}}{{{z^n}}}} \right| \ge \frac{{\left| {{a_n}} \right|}}{2}
> % MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
> % feaahmart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
> % hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
> % 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
> % vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
> % fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaWaaqWaaeaaca
> % WGHbWaaSbaaSqaaiaad6gaaeqaaOGaey4kaSYaaSaaaeaacaWGHbWa
> % aSbaaSqaaiaad6gacqGHsislcaaIXaaabeaaaOqaaiaadQhaaaGaey
> % 4kaSIaaiOlaiaac6cacaGGUaGaey4kaSYaaSaaaeaacaWGHbWaaSba
> % aSqaaiaaigdaaeqaaaGcbaGaamOEamaaCaaaleqabaGaamOBaiabgk
> % HiTiaaigdaaaaaaOGaey4kaSYaaSaaaeaacaWGHbWaaSbaaSqaaiaa
> % icdaaeqaaaGcbaGaamOEamaaCaaaleqabaGaamOBaaaaaaaakiaawE
> % a7caGLiWoacqGHLjYSdaabdaqaaiaadggadaWgaaWcbaGaamOBaaqa
> % baaakiaawEa7caGLiWoacqGHsisldaabdaqaamaalaaabaGaamyyam
> % aaBaaaleaacaWGUbGaeyOeI0IaaGymaaqabaaakeaacaWG6baaaiab
> % gUcaRiaac6cacaGGUaGaaiOlaiabgUcaRmaalaaabaGaamyyamaaBa
> % aaleaacaaIXaaabeaaaOqaaiaadQhadaahaaWcbeqaaiaad6gacqGH
> % sislcaaIXaaaaaaakiabgUcaRmaalaaabaGaamyyamaaBaaaleaaca
> % aIWaaabeaaaOqaaiaadQhadaahaaWcbeqaaiaad6gaaaaaaaGccaGL
> % hWUaayjcSdGaeyyzIm7aaSaaaeaadaabdaqaaiaadggadaWgaaWcba
> % GaamOBaaqabaaakiaawEa7caGLiWoaaeaacaaIYaaaaaaa!7560!
> $$

This crops up in Elias Wegert's Visual Complex Functions(p.62). Can someone please explain the second inequality (for me)?
[image]

If satisfied (true) then the implication then is that:
$$\left| {\frac{{{a_{n - 1}}}}{z} + ... + \frac{{{a_1}}}{{{z^{n - 1}}}} + \frac{{{a_0}}}{{{z^n}}}} \right| \ge \frac{{\left| {{a_n}} \right|}}{2}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaWaaqWaaeaada
% WcaaqaaiaadggadaWgaaWcbaGaamOBaiabgkHiTiaaigdaaeqaaaGc
% baGaamOEaaaacqGHRaWkcaGGUaGaaiOlaiaac6cacqGHRaWkdaWcaa
% qaaiaadggadaWgaaWcbaGaaGymaaqabaaakeaacaWG6bWaaWbaaSqa
% beaacaWGUbGaeyOeI0IaaGymaaaaaaGccqGHRaWkdaWcaaqaaiaadg
% gadaWgaaWcbaGaaGimaaqabaaakeaacaWG6bWaaWbaaSqabeaacaWG
% UbaaaaaaaOGaay5bSlaawIa7aiabgwMiZoaalaaabaWaaqWaaeaaca
% WGHbWaaSbaaSqaaiaad6gaaeqaaaGccaGLhWUaayjcSdaabaGaaGOm
% aaaaaaa!5421!
$$

Comment: Looks like they are trying to find a z that fulfills this rather than asserting it is true for all z

Comment: That's what I concluded also but he does not.

Comment: Who is "he"? Also I think your edited implication should be less than or equal to.

Answer (score 1):

The second inequality is not true in general.

For example, take $a_n=0$ and $a_{n-1}=a_{n-2}=\cdots=a_0=z=1$.

Then,

$$\left| {{a_n}} \right| - \left| {\frac{{{a_{n - 1}}}}{z} + ... + \frac{{{a_1}}}{{{z^{n - 1}}}} + \frac{{{a_0}}}{{{z^n}}}} \right| = -n < 0 = \frac{|a_n|}{2}$$

Comment: Does this mean I don't understand the book or has the book erred?

Answer (score 0):

I get it now. He (the author) is correct. The line above the equation is the clue (see (click) picture). Then the sum in the modulus is a sum of null sequences hence  can be made to vanish by taking delta (positive) small enough. That then leaves just  the other positive term of which half-of is clearly less than.